# How to get OpportunityLineItemSchedule Installment Period (Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly)

Tags: apex, opportunitylineitemschedule

Where can I get the Installment Period (Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly) from OpportunityLineItemSchedule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to just query a field for this. The UI makes this a feature so it's easy to schedule the products when adding products, but there's no underlying field, since the dates can be freely adjusted before saving the schedule. You would need to examine each line item schedule and make a determination of how many days apart each is, and based on the date frequencies, you can determine which schedule type was most likely used to establish the schedule.